# realloc(): Invalid next size C dump

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm having some serious trouble with this function: When the trace reaches the realloc, it blows up. I've checked similar questions on this subject but nothing came out. I hope you can help me. Do you see anything wrong?

```
char **tokenizepath(char *path){    

    char str[256]; // buffer;
    char **token=NULL;
    char *saveptr; 
    int i=1;
    size_t tam = sizeof(char*);

    token = malloc(2 * tam);
    strcpy(str, path);

    if(str[0]=='\\'){
        token[0] = "\\";
        token[i++] = strtok_r(str, "\\", &saveptr);
    }else{
        token[0] = strtok_r(str, "\\", &saveptr);
    }

    while((token[i]=strtok_r(NULL, "\\", &saveptr))!=NULL){
        i++;
        token = realloc(token, (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
    }

    return token;

}
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
* glibc detected * /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000605290 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a6e6)[0x7ffff7ab56e6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7d3e7)[0x7ffff7ab83e7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0xf9)[0x7ffff7ab9b39]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x40319b]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x400c31]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff7a5c30d]
/home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev[0x400aa9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 542669                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 00:14 542669                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 00:14 542669                             /home/vlad/workspace_SisOp/RFSDev/Debug/RFSDev
00605000-00626000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff0000000-7ffff0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff0021000-7ffff4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff5ad9000-7ffff5aee000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff5aee000-7ffff5ced000 ---p 00015000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff5ced000-7ffff5cee000 r--p 00014000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff5cee000-7ffff5cef000 rw-p 00015000 08:16 526333                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff5cef000-7ffff7a3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:14 273074                     /home/vlad/Sistemas Operativos/ext2.disk
7ffff7a3b000-7ffff7bd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffff7bd2000-7ffff7dd1000 ---p 00197000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffff7dd1000-7ffff7dd5000 r--p 00196000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7dd6000 rw-p 0019a000 08:16 526221                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7ffff7dd6000-7ffff7ddc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ddc000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffff7fe2000-7ffff7fe5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff9000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00020000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00021000 08:16 523159                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If the first test is TRUE:

```
if(str[0]=='\\'){
```

then in the first iteration of the following while loop:

```
while((token[i]=strtok_r(NULL, "\\", &saveptr))!=NULL){
```

i == 2 and you are attempting to access `token[2]` before it's been allocated.

---

Another problem: if the `token` array moves after a call to realloc (because realloc couldn't increase the size without moving it), then `saveptr` will no longer be valid.

Comment: Thanks, but I changed the initial token = malloc(2 * tam); for token = malloc(3 * tam); and didn't worked, still the same error u.u

Comment: You need to step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on

Comment: I did, it just dumps when the program reaches the realloc call

Comment: I spotted another problem which I've added to my answer above. However you really just need to step through the code in your debugger and inspect the state of all your local variables immediately prior to the crash.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that saveptr will no longer be valid. Also I've commented the realloc and now it dumps on another realloc ahead of this one, in other function.
Even more, valgrind is showing me that that piece of code actually executes several times, but it just says that blocks are definitely lost.
I think the problem is not my code... Can you think of any configuration problem that produces such behaviour?
Thank you very much for your patience